# Are ST the same as UV in a COLLADA file?

Tags: opengl, import, textures, collada

Are ST the same as UV in a COLLADA (.dae) file? (Exported from Cinema4D, COLLADA 1.4) I am having some trouble trying to add a texture to a object and I am wondering if it is because I have been using ST as UV. I'm not sure if this is necessary but it doesn't hurt to say I suppose. I'm using FreeGlut and I am trying to make a 3D model viewer that can already load  .obj and .dae but only geometry. Hopefully textures to if I can figure this out.

Comment: Yes, they are the same. You might also see STP for 3d texcoords.